# How to log the final URL after proxy in nginx?

Tags: nginx

For debugging reason I want to find the full URL after proxy.

e.g.

```
events{}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 0.0.0.0;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";

            proxy_pass http://kibana.logging.svc.cluster.local:5601;
        }
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    }
}
```

In this if I do `curl 0.0.0.0/kibana`

I should get the log `http://kibana.logging.svc.cluster.local:5601/kibana`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a real solution.

For this I added a temporary nginx server and made the first server forward to this second server.

Then I checked the logs of the second server.

Removing

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

solved my problem